# How to know which devenv process to kill when multiple VS are open

Tags: visual-studio, process, taskmanager

I have 3 Visual Studio 2012 open at the same time. One just got stuck and i need to kill it but in the Task manager i see 3 apparently identical devenv processes. I can't understand from memory usage which one to kill. Is there a way to know which solution is used by each process so that i can kill the stuck? 
Probably procMon is the answer but i'd like to avoid to open it if there's a faster way from TaskManager
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened different projects, use free tools like ProcessExplorer (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) and check the project that has been opened and terminate it.